# How to use a variable to specify column name in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, nse, r-faq

I have a ggplot command

```
ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes(x=name, y=rate, colour=majr, group=majr) )
```

inside a function. But I would like to be able to use a parameter of the function to pick out the column to use as colour and group. I.e. I would like something like this

```
f <- function( column ) {
    ...
    ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes(x=name, y=rate, colour= ??? , group=??? ) )
}
```

So that the column used in the ggplot is determined by the parameter. E.g. for f("majr") we get the effect of

```
ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes(x=name, y=rate, colour=majr, group=majr) )
```

but for f("gender") we get the effect of

```
  ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes(x=name, y=rate, colour=gender, group=gender) )
```

Some things I tried:

```
ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes(x=name, y=rate, colour= columnName , group=columnName ) )
```

did not work. Nor did

```
e <- environment() 
ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes(x=name, y=rate, colour= columnName , group=columnName ), environment=e )
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

**Note: the solution in this answer is "soft-deprecated". See the answer below using `.data[[` for the currently preferred method.**

You can use `aes_string`:

```
f <- function( column ) {
    ...
    ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes_string(x="name", y="rate", colour= column,
                                        group=column ) )
}
```

as long as you pass the column to the function as a string (`f("majr")` rather than `f(majr)` ). Also note that we changed the other columns, `"name"` and `"rate"`, to be strings.

If for whatever reason you'd rather not use `aes_string`, you could change it to (the somewhat more cumbersome):

```
    ggplot( rates.by.groups, aes(x=name, y=rate, colour= get(column),
                                        group=get(column) ) )
```

Comment: It's worth saying that you shouldn't/can't do `aes_string(x = rates.by.groups$name...`, and anyway you don't need to since you already passed the `ggplot(data = rates.by.groups...` argument. (The issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401681/ggplot-aes-string-does-not-work-inside-a-function))

Comment: Just adding a note to point people down to Moody_Mudskipper's answer with updates for ggplot2 version 3.0.0

Comment: @buncis That's not true, quoting `"column_name"` or `"column"` wouldn't work

Comment: @DavidRobinson sorry my mistake, I don't see the code is wrapped on a function with parameter, gonna delete my comment

Comment: "cumbersome"? Non-standard evaluation in R is ironically the most cumbersome "feature" I have ever encountered in a programming language. Truly maddening.

Answer (score 108):

From the [release notes](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.0.0) of `ggplot2 V3.0.0` :

> aes() now supports quasiquotation so that you can use !!, !!!,  and
>   :=. This replaces aes_() and aes_string() which are now 
>   soft-deprecated (but will remain around for a long time).

The idiomatic way now would be to convert to a symbol the string that the variable contains, using `sym()`(which is almost the same as base aliases `as.name()` / `as.symbol()`), and unquote it using `!!`

Simulating OP's data we can do :

```
library(tidyverse)
rates.by.groups <- data.frame(
  name = LETTERS[1:3],
  rate = 1:3,
  mjr = LETTERS[c(4,4,5)],
  gender = c("M","F","F")
)

f <- function(column) {
  column <- sym(column)
  ggplot(rates.by.groups, 
         aes(x = name, 
             y = rate, 
             fill  = !!column, 
             group = !!column)) +
    geom_col()
}

f("gender")
f("mjr")
x <- "gender"
f(x)
```

If we'd rather feed raw names to the function we can do:

```
f2 <- function(column) {
  column <- ensym(column)
  ggplot(rates.by.groups, 
         aes(x = name, 
             y = rate, 
             fill  = !!column, 
             group = !!column)) +
    geom_col()
}
```

It will work with names a.k.a. symbols AND with string literals

```
f2(gender)
f2(mjr)
f2("gender")
f2("mjr")
```

As Lionel says about `ensym()`:

> it's meant to mimic the syntax of arguments where you can supply both
>   in the LHS, e.g. list(bare = 1, "quoted" = 2)

---

A note on `enquo()`

`enquo()`quotes the expression (not necessarily a symbol) fed to the argument, it doesn't convert a string literal to a symbol as `ensym()` does so it might be less adapted here, but we can do :

```
f3 <- function(column) {
  column <- enquo(column)
  ggplot(rates.by.groups, 
         aes(x = name, 
             y = rate, 
             fill  = !!column, 
             group = !!column)) +
    geom_col()
}

f3(gender)
f2(mjr)
```

Comment: This **tidyeval** stuff is so annoying. The documentation for `aes()` itself talks about `enquo()` but it doesn't work. And whoever heard of `ensym()` before? BIG SIGH

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper For `f2`, all four examples work, and so does capturing the column name in a variable (i.e. `aname <- "mjr"; f2(aname)`). If I add code to manipulate the data frame using `dplyr` it attempts to find a column using the variable name and not the string in the variable name. In other words, how do I get `rates.by.groups %>% group_by(!!column)...` to work and still support the three  ways of calling `f2` ?

Comment: "so does capturing the column name in a variable" : it doesn't fail but it doesn't return the same result, `ensym` is designed to deal with arguments provided as names, and tolerate quotes around them. I believe you would like to treat the argument as a name, and to fall back on the value if the name is not found. This is actually what happens with `select`, but not with `group_by` ... It's possible to hack around it but not obvious. If it's important to you I think it would deserve its own question.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks. I was using both `select` and `group_by` so that was likely the issue. I can create a new question, but I need to come up with a simple example and check to see if it has been answered. I can post it if not.

Comment: How to use !! in case of `facet_grid`? It works with `facet_grid(cols = vars(!!column))` but throws an error with `facet_grid(~ !!column)`

Answer (score 69):

Another option (`ggplot2 > 3.0.0`) is to use the tidy evaluation pronoun [`.data`](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#data-masks) to slice the chosen variable/column from the `rates.by.groups` data frame.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58786401/786542)

```r
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic(base_size = 14))

# created by @Moody_Mudskipper
rates.by.groups <- data.frame(
  name = LETTERS[1:3],
  rate = 1:3,
  mjr = LETTERS[c(4, 4, 5)],
  gender = c("M", "F", "F")
)

f1 <- function(df, column) {
  gg <- ggplot(df, 
         aes(x = name, 
             y = rate, 
             fill  = .data[[column]], 
             group = .data[[column]])) +
    geom_col() +
    labs(fill = column)
  return(gg)
}

plot_list <- lapply(list("gender", "mjr"), function(x){ f1(rates.by.groups, x) })
plot_list
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```r
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```r
# combine all plots
library(egg)
ggarrange(plots = plot_list,
          nrow = 2,
          labels = c('A)', 'B)'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: The nicest thing about the .data[[  ]] approach is its generality. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is the canonical solution since rlang 0.4.* was introduced. This is also how it is proposed in the official vignette to ggplot2: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html

Comment: this actually works the best!

Answer (score 18):

Try using `aes_string` instead of `aes`.

Comment: This is great advice but can you tell them why? aes_string makes you use "" for non-variables and you use variables unquotes. 
aes_string(x = "foo", y = "fee", group = variable)

Comment: @mtelesha maybe because the variable have string as its value

Answer (score 18):

#### Do two things

1. Turn the column name into a symbol with `sym()`
2. Prepend `!!` to the symbol when you want to use it

#### Example

```
my_col <- sym("Petal.Length")

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = !!my_col)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `aes_string` does fix this problem, but does face an issue when adding error bars `geom_errorbar`. Below is a simple solution.

```
#Identify your variables using the names of your columns indie your dataset
 xaxis   <- "Independent"   
 yaxis   <- "Dependent"
 sd      <- "error"

#Specify error bar range (in 'a-b' not 'a'-'b')
 range   <- c(yaxis, sd)                                #using c(X, y) allows use of quotation marks inside formula
 yerrbar <- aes_string(ymin=paste(range, collapse='-'), 
                       ymax=paste(range, collapse='+'))


#Build the plot
  ggplot(data=Dataset, aes_string(x=xaxis, y=yaxis)) +
    geom_errorbar(mapping=yerrbar, width=15, colour="#73777a", size = 0.5) +
    geom_point   (shape=21)
```

Bonus, you can also add facets to your plot using these lines inside the ggplot:

```
facet_grid(formula(paste(Variable1, "~", Variable2)))
```

This script was modified from this original post: [ggplot2 - Error bars using a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327466/ggplot2-error-bars-using-a-custom-function)