# R: Using a variable name in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run this code in `ggplot2`. It runs perfectly fine.

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x= depth , y = price), color = cut))
p + geom_point()
```

Now I want to pass the `x` and `y` using variables so that I can use them in a for loop.

```
var1  <- colnames(diamonds)
```

`var1` is a vector with the following variables:

```
[1] "carat"   "cut"     "color"   "clarity" "depth"   "table"  
 [7] "price"   "x"       "y"       "z"
```

I use the following formula which should be equivalent to the above `ggplot2`.

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x= var1[5] , y = var1[7]), color = cut))
p + geom_point()
```

This time around `var1[5]` is treated as a variable and `var1[7]` as another variable instead of them getting resolved into depth and price.

Is there a way around. I have used paste function but does not look to be working.

Comment: use `aes_string`

Comment: Also see "Programming with ggplot2" to see how  to write reusable functions with ggplot2: https://rpubs.com/hadley/97970

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable to specify column name in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 2):

Like bunk allready mentioned in the comment: aes_string is the way to go:

```
library(ggplot2)
var1  <- colnames(diamonds)
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x= var1[5] , y = var1[7]), color = cut)
p + geom_point()
```