# R; replace variable with contents of the variable

Tags: r

How can I replace the variable by its content/value? See sample code below.

```
###########SET my plotting variable##########################
    plot_var_y<-'var1'
    plot_var_x<-'var2'
####################EVALUATE THE FOLLOWING##################
        temp$plot_var_y
        # The above expression evaluates to null which is not what I want.temp$var1 is what I was looking for

    plot1<-ggplot(aes(y = plot_var_y, x = as.factor(plot_var_x), fill = no_of_heads), data =temp) +
      geom_boxplot()+stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line",aes(group=1),colour=I("red"))+stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point",shape=18,size=3)+xlab("position")
```

Comment: Eventually `temp[[plot_var_y]]`

Comment: Thanks. How about inside ggplot function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aes_string` instead of `aes`

try

```
 plot1<-ggplot(aes_string(y = plot_var_y, x = as.factor(plot_var_x), fill = no_of_heads), data =temp) +
      geom_boxplot()+stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line",aes(group=1),colour=I("red"))+stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point",shape=18,size=3)+xlab("position")
```

See
[How to use a variable to specify column name in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot)