# scatter plot, colored by category variable, faceted over categorical variable in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have a data frame with a number of numeric and categorical variables.

```
data <- data.frame(dep_var = ...,
              cat1 = ...,
              cat2 = ...,
              ...
              num1 = ...,
              num2 = ...,
              ...)
```

If I choose a single numeric feature, I can plot it against the dependent variable, faceted by the categorical variables (ignore the fact that the legend takes up half of the page - I'm doing a high-level look for clusters)

```
cat_cols <- c("cat1", "cat2",... , "cat6")

data %>% select(dep_var, var1, cat_cols) %>%
  gather(category, value, -c(dep_var, var1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=var1, y=dep_var))+
  facet_wrap(~ category) + geom_point(aes(color=value))
```

[image: Good output]

However, if I try to wrap it up in a function and lapply, the plots don't work the same way:

```
num_cols <- ("num1", "num2", "num3",...)

lapply(names(data[num_cols]), 
       function(x) {
        data %>% select(dep_var, x, cat_cols) %>%
           gather(category, value, -c(dep_var, x)) %>%
           ggplot(aes(x=x, y=dep_var))+
           facet_wrap(~ category) + geom_point(aes(color=value))
       })
```

[image: Bad Output]

There is one of those types of plots for each of the numeric variables I have.  What am I missing in the lapply?

Comment: In the second example `x` is a string. That works ok for `select`, but `aes` expects a bare name, not a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable to specify column name in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot)

Comment: I'd recommend [this answer by Moody Mudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53168593/8366499) since it lets you mix strings and symbols in one `aes`, rather than having to choose one or the other.

Comment: Thank you @divibisan. The get() function in "How to use a variable..." got me past the issue. I wouldn't have thought to do a search like that since I wasn't entirely sure what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Using the get() function in the aes call to turn a string back into a "bare name" solved the issue:

```
lapply(names(data[num_cols]), 
       function(x) {
        data %>% select(dep_var, x, cat_cols) %>%
           gather(category, value, -c(dep_var, x)) %>%
           ggplot(aes(x=get(x), y=dep_var))+             //Fix here with get() function
           facet_wrap(~ category) + geom_point(aes(color=value))
       })
```