# R - Error when saving multiple plots in a loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe like this testframe, but much larger.

```
lat_area = seq (50, 40, -0.5)
lon_area = seq (-10, 10, 0.5)
grid_area = matrix(0, ncol=2, nrow=length(lon_area)*length(lat_area))
grid_area[,2] = rep(lat_area, each=length(lon_area))
grid_area[,1] = lon_area
testframe = as.data.frame(grid_area)

colnames(testframe) = c("Lon", "Lat")
testframe$FDsw = rep(c(0.5,0.7), length.out= nrow(testframe))
testframe$Thgf = rep(c(0.2,0.3), length.out= nrow(testframe))
testframe$Igbff = rep(c(0.8,0.9), length.out= nrow(testframe))
```

I want to make contourplots for each data-column (columns 3:5 in the testframe)
I found multiple question on how to save multiple plots automatially. the best way in my opinion is to save all plots in a list and then save them later from this list. My try is down below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)

plot_list = list()
for (i in 3:length(testframe)) {
  wd = map_data("world") 
  LP = ggplot() 
  LP = LP + 
    geom_contour_fill(data = testframe, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = colnames(testframe)[i]), breaks = MakeBreaks(0.1)) + 
    geom_contour(data = testframe, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = colnames(testframe)[i]), color = "blue", size = 0.6) + 
    geom_text_contour(data = testframe, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = colnames(testframe)[i]), stroke = 0.1) + 
    scale_fill_divergent() +
    geom_polygon(data = wd , aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour="black", fill = NA) + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(50, 40)) +
    scale_x_longitude(ticks = 10)+ scale_y_latitude(ticks = 10) +
    labs(title= paste("Plot", colnames(testframe)[i], sep = " ")) 
  plot_list[[i]] = LP}

plot_list[1:2] = NULL
names(plot_list) = colnames(testframe)[3:ncol(testframe)]


for (i in 1:3) {
  file_name = paste("Plot", i, ".tiff", sep="")
  tiff(file_name)
  print(plot_list[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I am getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("fullseq") : 
  no applicable method for 'fullseq' applied to an object of class "character"
In addition: Warning message:
In pretty.default(range(data$z, na.rm = TRUE), 10) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert variables into regular `aes()` statements because those are evaluated at print time. You need to pass sumbols and not strings, and variables aren't enclosed in the plot object. So something like

```
aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = colnames(testframe)[i])
```

won't work. With the latest version of ggplot2, you can insert symbols into the expression with a combination of `rlang::sym()` and the `!!` (bang bang) operator. Try

```
aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = !!rlang::sym(colnames(testframe)[i]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still get errors: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    labs(title= paste("Plot", colnames(testframe)[i], sep = " ")) 
  plot_list"
> 
> plot_list[1:2] = NULL
> names(plot_list) = colnames(testframe)[3:ncol(testframe)]
Error in names(plot_list) = colnames(testframe)[3:ncol(testframe)] : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [0]
> 
> 
> for (i in 1:3) {
+   file_name = paste("Plot", i, ".tiff", sep="")
+   tiff(file_name)
+   print(plot_list[[i]])
+   dev.off()
+ }
Error in plot_list[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Are you sure you get that with the code and data above? I just ran it with the change I suggested and didn't get that error.

Comment: Ok, seems like I did a mistake! Now its running! Thank you so much!