# Passing Column Names to ggplot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've written a function in R to produce a graph from a given data frame:

```
my_graph <- function (df, scale_fac)
{

  row_count = nrow(df)

  df %>% mutate(star_sign = as.numeric(factor(star_sign, levels = lvls))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(star_sign)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = mean), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(y = min), color = "blue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = max), color = "green") + 
    geom_col(aes(y = scale_fac * exposure), width = 0.5, fill = "blue") + 
    scale_y_continuous("Linear Predictor", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./scale_fac , name = "Exposure")) +
    scale_x_continuous("Star Sign", breaks = c(1:row_count), labels = df$lvls) +
    theme_bw()

}

df <- data.frame(star_sign = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces"),
                 exposure = c(50, 70, 60, 40, 45, 78, 42, 22, 28, 49, 50, 31),
                 mean = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.3))

df$min <- 0.95 * df$mean
df$max <- 1.05 * df$mean

df$lvls = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces")

my_graph(df, 1/150)
```

However there are some hard coded bits in the `ggplot()` statement such as `exposure`, `mean`, `min`, `max` which I'd like to get rid of by passing the names of the fields as additional function parameters, but I can't work out how to do it. I first tried using the `[[]]` notation, but it didn't work. I then discovered that there's a `!!` notation in `tidyverse` but to test this I modified my function definition to include a `mean_name` parameter and then referred to `!!mean_name` instead of `mean` inside the `ggplot()` statement:

```
my_graph_2 <- function (df, mean_name, scale_fac)
{
  df %>% mutate(star_sign = as.numeric(factor(star_sign, levels = df$lvls))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(star_sign)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = !!mean_name), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(y = min), color = "blue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = max), color = "green") + 
    geom_col(aes(y = scale_fac * exposure), width = 0.5, fill = "blue") + 
    scale_y_continuous("Linear Predictor", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./scale_fac , name = "Exposure")) +
    scale_x_continuous("Star Sign", breaks = c(1:row_count), labels = df$lvls) +
    theme_bw()
}

df <- data.frame(star_sign = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces"),
                 exposure = c(50, 70, 60, 40, 45, 78, 42, 22, 28, 49, 50, 31),
                 mean = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.3))

df$min <- 0.95 * df$mean
df$max <- 1.05 * df$mean

df$lvls = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces")

my_graph_2(df, "mean", 1/150)
```

When I run this I see:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

which I don't understand. Can anyone help please?

Update: if I use `aes_string()` it seems to work. Revised function definition:

```
my_graph <- function (df, mean_name, scale_fac)
{
  row_count = nrow(df)

  df %>% mutate(star_sign = as.numeric(factor(star_sign, levels = lvls))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(star_sign)) +
    #geom_line(aes(y = mean), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes_string(y = mean_name), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(y = min), color = "blue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = max), color = "green") + 
    geom_col(aes(y = scale_fac * exposure), width = 0.5, fill = "blue") + 
    scale_y_continuous("Linear Predictor", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./scale_fac , name = "Exposure")) +
    scale_x_continuous("Star Sign", breaks = c(1:row_count), labels = df$lvls) +
    theme_bw()
}
```

Comment: Can you use `aes_string`?

Comment: BTW, should `labels=df$lvls` be just `labels = lvls`?

Comment: Thank you. I did try removing the df$ from the labels part but I saw errors sadly. aes_string does seem to work though - have edited my original post above...

Comment: `!!` isn't for strings, i.e, when you use `!!` I would expect your call to be `my_graph_2(df, mean, 1/150)`, without quotes around `"mean"`. But overall, I think you should read through the [FAQ on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53168593/903061). It's got several worked examples.