# Try to put multiple ggplot into one image but all plot are same

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am trying to put multiple ggplot chart into one but all the plot are same, please help with below example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

url <- paste("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/",
  "data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv",
  sep = ""
)
df <- read_csv(url)
cols_to_factor <- c("Major", "Major_code", "Major_category")
df <- df %>%
  mutate_at(cols_to_factor, factor)
df_clean <- df %>% drop_na()

plot_list <- list()
i <- 0
for (variable in colnames(select_if(df_clean, is.numeric))) {
  i <- i + 1
  g <- ggplot(df_clean) +
    geom_histogram(aes(unlist(df_clean[, variable])),
      bins = 20,
      fill = "royalblue", color = "gray"
    ) +
    ggtitle(paste("Histogram of", variable)) +
    labs(x = variable)
  plot_list[[i]] <- g
}
grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list, ncol = 5)
```

The plot_list does have values inside, but I don't know why they are all same. Each loop the value should be different. If I add `plot(g)` befor `plot_list[[i]]<-g`, it can draw the correct chart. I am out of ideas, please kindly help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with `facet_wrap()`

```
library(tidyverse)

df_clean %>% 
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 20, fill = "royalblue", color = "gray") + 
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way you select your column from your dataframe by a loop can be achieved by using the `.data[[]]` notation explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot). Here is the output:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

url <- paste("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/",
             "data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv",
             sep = ""
)
df <- read_csv(url)

cols_to_factor <- c("Major", "Major_code", "Major_category")
df <- df %>%
  mutate_at(cols_to_factor, factor)
df_clean <- df %>% drop_na()

plot_list <- list()
i <- 0
for (variable in colnames(select_if(df_clean, is.numeric))) {
  i <- i + 1
  g <- ggplot(df_clean) +
    geom_histogram(aes(.data[[variable]]),
                   bins = 20,
                   fill = "royalblue", color = "gray"
    ) +
    ggtitle(paste("Histogram of", variable)) +
    labs(x = variable)
  plot_list[[i]] <- g
}
grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list, ncol = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>